# collider does not follow

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a problem, I did everything like in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7iYWpzL9GkM but when the sword collider activates , sword collider is not located near the character, but goes to the edge,but if I leave the collider enabled, then it will be located near the character correctly

[original position sword collider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbhbn.png)
[as long as I don't attack with the left mouse button everything is fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZoyh.png)
[after clicking the collider goes away](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDViN.png)

I tried to bind the collider to the character, but I don’t know how to do it. In the end, it should have turned out like in the video, I hit the slime and it disappears, but for some reason the collider goes away when hit

Comment: the box went away because you disabled the collider

Comment: then why does the slime disappear in the video? if his collider was also supposed to go to the side

Comment: sorry but im not going to watch a 90 minute youtube video to play guess what you did differently.   "bind" the collider, it just needs to be a child. but all this is almost 100% likely to be in the video..  why it goes away in your code? who knows, you wrote it.. we cant see it

Answer (score 0):

I realised what the problem was, the collider was moving away because my character was not at 0 0 0 position, so most likely when the character moved, the collider moved to the zero position, and the character to the position that was specified in the unity.